# Deriving ADF unit root test form for the time series with quadratic deterministic trend

Tags: econometrics, regression, self-study, time-series

I have the following time series process $y_t $

$$\Delta y_t = \delta + \gamma t + \epsilon_t$$

where $e_t$ is white noise process with the variance of $\sigma^2$.

I guess that whereas $\Delta y_t$ is trend stationary process, $y_t$ is a random walk with a quadratic deterministic trend.

So, by using the process $y_t$ which is defined as a random walk with a quadratic deterministic trend, I want to apply the ADF unit root test. During the testing procedure, which form do we assign to $y_t$ under the null hypothesis?

What I did is as follows:

My solution is that! But my solution is totally wrong. I just want to exhibit my attempt, so I added them as a picture because this solution is too long to type it and it is wrong. (Sorry for not typing )

But, I have no idea other than this solution. Please share your ideas with me. Thank you a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: *duplicate post